# How can I store data from OnPostExecute()?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to get the id numbers of foods from the [USDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Department_of_Agriculture) database. My issue is that I can get the JSON data, but I can not take it out of the `OnPostCreate()` function. When I iterate through `JSONdataWIthIDs` in the `OnPostCreate()` all the data is there. But when I try to use the data someplace else, it is empty. How do I store the data into an array?

Here is the constructor.

```
public USDA(String nameOfFoodToSearchFor) {

    setJSONdataWIthIDs(nameOfFoodToSearchFor);

    // This returns 0
    Log.i("TAG", "SONdataWIthIDs size: " + JSONdataWIthIDs.size());

    // This does not work.
    for(String s: JSONdataWIthIDs)
    {
        Log.i("TAG OUTPUT", s);
    }
}
```

Here is the code with the OnPostCreate.

```
private void setJSONdataWIthIDs(String nameOfFood) {

    final String url1 = "https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=" + nameOfFood + "&sort=n&max=25&offset=0&api_key=x5qM9v8PkjZrTf2cVSHzoK7y4GsSBgoQEmJsbwqV";

    AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url1)
                    .build();

            Response response = null;

            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                return response.body().string();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {

            String lines[] = o.toString().split("\\r?\\n");

            for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
            {
                JSONdataWIthIDs.add(lines[i]);
            }

            // This works
            for(String s : JSONdataWIthIDs)
            {
                Log.i("TAG", s);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: Write another method within same class where your async task belongs to and pass that array to mothod.

Comment: You mean within the asynctask or outside of it?

Comment: within same activity but outside aysync task (i consider you've written async task within same class as that of activity)

Answer (score 0):

onPostExecute is where the execution flow comes back from the worker thread (that is what supports AsyncTask) to the UI thread. Your log line,

```
   Log.i("TAG", "SONdataWIthIDs size: " + JSONdataWIthIDs.size());
```

happens in the UI thread and is running in parallel with the working thread at that moment. So the result is not available.

Comment: I had an idea that something like that was going on.  What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Depend on what you want to do with the JSON data. Either you want to update some UI element like ListView/RecycerView or want to store the JSON data in some form. the only access point you have to the JSON data is onPostExecute. Outside of it you lose the reference to it because we are talking about "callback" here and unlike regular method where you can expect a return type, callback is event trigger and does not really have a "return" value like a method does.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite simple. The `Log.i("TAG", "SONdataWIthIDs size: " + JSONdataWIthIDs.size());` statement is executed before the `onPostExecute()`. So the `JSONdataWIthIDs` is empty.

The call to async task is done asynchronously (`doInBackground()`). And you are saving the value to `JSONdataWIthIDs` in `onPostExecute()`. So you can access the id's only after the async task is done.

> How do I store the data into an array?

The data is already stored into the array in `onPostExecute()`. The only problem is that you can access it only after the `onPostExecute()` is called.

Comment: Okay, I had an idea that something like that was going on. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: `onPostExecute()` is the method that gets called when the `task is done`. So the safest place to access `JSONdataWIthIDs` in your case is within `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: I will need to use the data JsondataWithIDs outside of the thread. Hence, the dilemma.

Comment: `onPostExecute()` is in the UI Thread. So it's outside the Background thread.

Comment: Okay, maybe I am going about this the wrong way. I ultimately need to get data from the USDA link. Is there a way to do without creating another thread? If so, which way do you recommend?